# Execvp not being executed n times in a loop

Tags: c

Assume input is a pointer to array, which at each elements stores, "ls -l" at position 0, then cat helloworld.txt at position 1, and so forth, I wish to create the main parameter, which is ls, cat, pwd, and execute it. Essentially, what I am doing is I have a file with all those commands, I first store them in my input variable, which is declared as char *input[10]. Now I have what I need in that array, and I am able to extract the individual main commands, like ls, cat, and I wish to execute all of them.

For example,

if position 0 had ls -l, my first variable has ls and I wish to pass that to execvp and then position 1 might have cat sample.txt, now my variable first will be cat, and I pass that to execvp along with the entire cat sample.txt(which is input[i]), to execvp. For some strange reason, this is not working. How can I run all those commands in a loop in an execvp such that once it's done, all those commands have ran successfully. Here is my attempt, at the end of the first loop, I run an execvp, I expect that to finish, and then I extract further input, etc, etc.

Help me out.

```
       for(i=0; i<lineCount; i++)
        {

            first = malloc(sizeof(char)*50); 

            for(j=0; j<strlen(input[i]); j++)
            {
                if(input[i][j]!=' ')
                {
                    first[j]=input[i][j];
                }
                else
                {    
                    break;
                }
            } 

            execvp(first, input[i]);

         }
```

I tried doing execp(first, input) but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use execvp() once , the context of execution of the process that involved will be changed , except the pid of the process that called execvp , hence your loop won't work since once execvp() , there won't be any more iterations.

execvp() is mainly meant to be called by a child process , in your case for 'n' number of execvp() calls , there must have neen 'n' number of child processes forked,

Good Practices:

- Using  execl, execv, execle, execve, execlp, execvp , family of system calls , with child processes.
- After the new process image is loaded to child , and after execution , collect the exit code of process launched , and perform any necessary error handling.
- The child processes are now in a zombie state , the parent process must exexute wait()/waitpid() , and wait till all the child processes are terminated , and then exit.

-- Edit --
POC code for OP's reference

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>




int  main(void)
{
pid_t cpid;
int   status = 0;

cpid = fork();
  if (cpid == 0)
  {
   char *cmd[] = { "ls", "-l", (char *)0 };
   int ret = execv ("/bin/ls", cmd);
  }
wait(&status);
  if(status < 0)
     perror("Abnormal exit of program ls");
  else
     printf("Exit Status of ls is %d",status);
}
```

Comment: I understand that, now I have the execvp outside the loop running it once, and its not even running once, can you explain why?

Comment: That is because your calling execvp() in a wrong way , the first parameter is a null terminated string of the path to the process image you want to launch.The second parameter must be the arguments to the program , you will launch , see the usage here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/exec.html

Comment: my first parameter is ls, second parameter is ls -l how is that wrong?

Comment: @RichardMckenna , i have posted a reference code , have a loook at it and build your program in a similiar way.

Comment: I know how to do that, my inquiry is how to run MULTIPLE execvps, I don't understand the concept of hwo to use wait to have say 4 execvps run in one program

Comment: use one execvp for each child process id , use a if statement , and using getpid() , check if the pid is of the child that you want to launch the program with , launch it and then do the same for other child processes

Comment: @RichardMckenna , I have once written a similiar program ,download it from here https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=07C2FD17B2A9B9F4&id=7C2FD17B2A9B9F4%211471 , the only difference is i have used execl() instead of execvp() , make the appropriate changes. Also i have used waitpid() , you change your it to wait() , its much more simple

Comment: I understand how your code works now. So my only question which has been bothering me for a while is how does wait, and waitpid work? I have read tutorials, but how exactly have you used it and why do we use it?

Comment: let me explain the case of waitpid() , you use it like this waitpid(cpid , &status , options) , here the parent process will wait till cpid finishes executing , the process image , and then stores status in &status , you pass NULL to options , unless you planning on using any , one more way to do it is waitpid(-1,&status,NULL) , in this case passing -1 in the pid field , will make the parent process wait for ALL the child processes you forked to terminate

Comment: But I don't understand how you are actually waiting, since in your cleanprocs, you have a while do loop, and I was wondering if you can elaborate on that.

Comment: In do{wait_stat = waitpid(-1,&status,0); //code }while(wait_stat > 0) , the parent hangs near waitpid , and always returns the pid of the process its waiting on , once all processes finish , waitpid will just return a negative number , indicating that the wait is over , hence the loop will be broken.  Am sure you will find more clarity about these function by referring the man page , just type man <function> , in your linux terminal , in this case its "man waitpid" , am sure by studying the parameters and return values , you will be able to understand that code

Comment: so do you clean the processes after you execute it(using your logic), for some strange reason, I am getting my behavior, but it is printing out over 20 times, even though all I wanted was 5 times. I suspect that maybe its because the cleanprocess is after the executeprocess?

Comment: yes clean is definitely after execute.....my program is not perfect ,  follow it exactly , i just wanted you to use the same idea.

Comment: what would explain the 25 calls?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what [the opengroup exec manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/exec.html) says, in the first paragraph:

> There shall be no return from a successful exec, because the calling
>   process image is overlaid by the new process image.

I suggest reading [the opengroup fork manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/fork.html), and using fork and exec in conjunction.

Comment: I am using fork, that code is in the child process. So does that mean I can not run multiple execvps, each one has to be ran on a seperate fork? How would I then run multiple execvps from a file. Like, if it has ls -l, pwd, how would I run them all back to back?

Comment: That is what [the opengroup wait manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/wait.html) is for.

Answer (score 1):

`exec` *replaces* the running process with the one you `exec`, and so it never returns on `success` because the process will be replaced.

If you want to run a bunch of processes, the simple way is to use a utility function like `popen` or `system` to run them. For complete control, use the usual UNIX `fork`/`exec` combo once for each command you want to run.

Comment: Ok, but for now, why isn't just ONE running? I understand if they all didn't run, but one should at least run. If first = "ls", and input[i] at the instant is "ls -l", shouldn't that work? I am using fork, and it's in my child process.

Comment: @RichardMckenna: the parameter array is each parameter on it's own, spaces in the "command line" are delimiters. The very first parameter is the program executable file path. So your "input" array would be `{"/bin/ls", "-l", 0}`. Each execvp must be done in its very own forked process, as execve will not return, but replace the process image.

Comment: @datenwolf If I am using execvp, I don't need to specify the path. How exactly would I use execvp, so first parameter is ls, what is the second parameter, how would it know the difference between ls and ls -l

Comment: @RichardMckenna: As the documentation says, the first argument is the program to run, and the second argument is the list of arguments (`argv`) to pass. You'd put the `-l` in that second argument. You will get further by **reading the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/exec.html)**.